# Backbone.js: resetting a collection causes error in model.save

Tags: backbone.js

I have a webapp where I am implementing a list of folders. Whenever a folder is clicked, it contents are shown.

After clicking on various folders, thus displaying their contents, I found out that triggering an event on a folder item, multiple models were responding to the event - models for list item appearing in more than one list were not removed when changing folders.

So, I started using this function to remove the collection of list items in a folder.

```
this.collection.reset()
```

my problem was solved but now when I try to persist a model to db, I always get the following error...

```
A "url" property or function must be specified
```

any idea why this is being caused by `this.collection.reset()`???

Comment: Is the `model` property of the collection set?

Comment: Yes, the `model` property is set.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, you have an event binding somewhere that calls `fetch()` when `reset` event is triggered. Look for any `bind('reset', ...)` statements in your code.